# orthogonal transformation between two families of orthogonal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $m\ge n$ and $A$ and $B$ be two $m\times n$ matrices such that the columns of $A$ form an orthonormal set and so does the columns of $B$. In terms of matrix multiplication, this means:

$$A^TA=I_n=B^TB.$$

Now, suppose the column spaces of $A$ and $B$ are the same $n-$dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^m$, is it true that there is an $n\times n$ orthogonal (or orthonormal) matrix $O$ such that $AO=B$?
Or equivalently $A^TB$ is orthogonal? 
$$B^TAA^TB=A^TBB^TA=I_n ?$$

I checked it with $m=3, n=2$. Geometrically there should always be an orthonormal transformation sending a pair of orthonormal vectors to another pair of orthonormal vectors in a two-dim plane of the three-dim space.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a $m\times(m-n)$ matrix containing an orthonormal basis for the orthogonal complement of the column space of $A,B$. It means that the matrices
$$
\tilde A =  [A| C],\qquad \tilde B =[B|C] 
$$
are orthogonal, since $\tilde A^T\tilde A = I_m = \tilde B^T \tilde B$. It also implies
$$\tilde A \tilde A^T = AA^T + CC^T = I_m = BB^T + CC^T =\tilde B \tilde B^T$$ 
$$\implies AA^T = BB^T \implies A(A^TB) = B. $$
To conclude that $ A^T B$ is orthogonal, notice that $\tilde A^T\tilde B$ is also orthogonal, and
$$
\tilde A^T \tilde B = \begin{pmatrix}A^TB & 0 \\ 0 & I_{m-n} \end{pmatrix}
\implies I_m = \tilde A^T \tilde B\tilde B^T \tilde A = \begin{pmatrix}A^TBB^TA & 0 \\ 0 & I_{m-n} \end{pmatrix}\implies A^TBB^TA = I_n.
$$